# How Can I Best Perform This Kinda Of Table Relationship?

Tags: mysql

i'm developing Fantasy App.

I create one table called 'Tournaments' and one table called 'Entries'.

I want have the total number of entries for each tournament.

I really don't want query everytime the table 'Entries' to count the number of entries for each 'Tournament'. So i think in put also some column on 'Tournaments' table calling column 'entries_total'.

How is the best way to perform this ?

To resume the goal: Have the total number of tournaments entries in an column on the 'Tournaments' table.

Comment: please add sample data with the tables and the columns. I will attempt to answer your question but without more data, I might be wrong

Comment: Are you using the three databases for the same App? mysql, postgresql and sqlite? If not, please, tag only the RDBMs you are using.

Comment: Create a trigger on inserts to the 'Entries' table to update the 'entries_total' on the relevant record in the 'Tournament' table.

Comment: `select t.id, t.tournament, count(e.entries) over (partition by t.tournament) as enteriesTur
    from #Tournaments t
    join #Enteries e on  t.id = e.id`   this will only give you the results. As @kbbucks said, you should create a trigger if you don't want to query all the time

Comment: This is what i have guys: http://grab.by/MlkQ

Comment: As i said, how i setup this 'Tournament' table to have an counter of how much 'Entries' each specific tournament have.